# How do I get stripe's application fee to reflect the adjustable quantity during checkout?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I added the adjustable quantity for Stripe's check out session call. I understand that the fee object is created after the payment.

I'm looking at the application fee object in stripe's documentation and it says it is capped at the final charge amount. How do I retrieve the charge amount or better, quantity during the checkout session?

```
    checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                success_url=domain_url + 'success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
                cancel_url=domain_url + 'cancelled/',
                payment_method_types=['card'],
                customer=customer.id,
                payment_intent_data={
                    'application_fee_amount': int(stripe_price * fee_percentage),
                    'transfer_data': {
                    'destination': seller.stripe_user_id,
                    },
                },
                line_items=[
                {
                    'price_data': {
                        'currency': currency,
                        'unit_amount': price,
                        'product_data': {
                            'name': title
                        },
                    },
                    'adjustable_quantity': {
                    'enabled': True,
                    'minimum': 0,
                    'maximum': available_quantity,
                  },
                  'quantity': 1,
                },
                ],
                metadata={
                    "product_id": product.id,
                    "client_reference_id": user.id,
                },
                mode='payment',

            )
            return JsonResponse({'sessionId': checkout_session['id']})
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the best option is to do the following:

1. Set [`payment_method_data.capture_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-capture_method) to `manual` on the Checkout Session
2. When the Checkout Session is complete [set an `application_fee_amount` when capturing the funds](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/capture#capture_payment_intent-application_fee_amount)

This limits you to payment methods that support separate authorization and capture, but it will allow you to set `application_fee_amount` after the Checkout Session completes.

Comment: There's no more webhook events for checkout.session.completed when payment method is set to manual. Does that mean the approach here would be to attain the session Id, get the payment intent from that session id, and create another view that lets the seller click on a button to retrieve the payment intent and then set it to complete?

Comment: No, you should listen for [`payment_intent.amount_capturable_updated`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-payment_intent.amount_capturable_updated) events to determine when [the Payment Intent associated with the Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-payment_intent) has an amount ready to be captured.